# W1000 Symbol 'StrLComp' is deprecated: 'Moved to the AnsiStrings unit'

Tags: delphi

I am working on the project where I found the warnings as

`W1000 Symbol 'StrLComp' is deprecated: 'Moved to the AnsiStrings unit'`

There are so many warnings in my code for many of the string functions defined in the `System.SysUtils`.

I am not able to use the `AnsiStrings` functions because it makes multiple occurrences.

Can anyone please tell me How I can remove these type of warnings?

I am working on Delphi 10 Seattle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These warnings are dealt with quite readily by using the `System.AnsiStrings` unit, just as the warning instructs you. Use that unit, listing it after `System.SysUtils` in your `uses` clause, and the warning will no longer be produced.

If you include both `System.SysUtils` and `System.AnsiStrings` then you will encounter an ambiguous overload error when calling this function with an Ansi string as input. That will need to be resolved by qualifying the function name:

```
System.AnsiStrings.StrLComp(...)
```

or

```
AnsiStrings.StrLComp(...)
```

Depending on whether or not you use namespace aliases.

Before you go down this path, you might want to take a step back and consider if you really want to continue calling this *ANSI* function. Can you not use the Unicode version instead?  If you can do so, this entire issue disappears.